# Session-cookies: Weird Behaviour? Or Have I not understood something here?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Here is the piece of code:

```
session_name('somename');
session_start();
echo 'session name:'.session_name();
```

The above does print the session name as *somename*.
If I append the code below,

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['somename'])) {
 echo "<br/><br/>"."Cookie somename not yet set";
 }
else {
 echo "<br/><br/>".var_dump($_COOKIE['somename']);
 }
```

The output is always

> Cookie somename not yet set.

*Am I using the **isset** function wrong?*

If I just append this:

```
 echo "<br/><br/>".var_dump($_COOKIE['somename']);
```

Then, the output for the first time is:

> session name:somename
>   Notice: Undefined index: somename in /path/to/file.php on line 12 NULL

If I refresh the page, then the output is

> session name:somename
>   string(26) "367jr029jj17mdu5fgkfgiv0u6"

*Isn't the cookie variable supposed to get **set before the page content is loaded?** or Have I not understood sessions/cookies?*

Comment: I don't like your indentation style very much.

Comment: Also, don't post solutions in the question.

Comment: Feel free to post your eventual solution as a self-answer.

Comment: You wrote your solution in your question. I edited it out. Feel free to re-post it as an answer.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal what!? and this is a dumb question. Caused by my oversight. I regret that I asked this question here!!

Comment: Which part of my comments are you having trouble understanding? I cannot answer "what!?".

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I had posted the answer in the question because the question was dumb. So that people wont waste their time looking through the answers for a dumb question. Nothing more!

Comment: Yes, I know, but that is not how this site works. Questions go in questions; answers go in answers.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal you are acting really weird! Now you down-vote! I have better work to do than chat with you here. Sry.

Comment: You openly admit that it's a dumb question, then berate me for downvoting it? You're the weird one. See ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [Jani Hartikainen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8516365/911182)

`isset()` checks to see if `$_COOKIE['somename']` is set.

First time through *before* cookies are set:

```
// $_COOKIE['somename'] is NOT set so skip to else
if(isset($_COOKIE['somename'])) {
 echo "<br/><br/>"."Cookie somename not yet set";
 }
else {
 // $_COOKIE['somename'] is NOT set so you get an error.
 echo "<br/><br/>".var_dump($_COOKIE['somename']);
 }
```

Second time through *after* cookies are set:

```
// $_COOKIE['somename'] is set so show message
if(isset($_COOKIE['somename'])) {
 echo "<br/><br/>"."Cookie somename not yet set";
 }
else {
 // $_COOKIE['somename'] is set so skip this part.
 echo "<br/><br/>".var_dump($_COOKIE['somename']);
 }
```

A more appropriate use of `isset` would be something like:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['somename'])) {
 echo "<br/><br/>".var_dump($_COOKIE['somename']);
 }
else {
  echo "<br/><br/>"."Cookie somename not yet set";
 }
```

In the last example I use `isset` to determine if `$_COOKIE['somename']` has been set. If so, then I dump it; otherwise, I show the message “Cookie somename not yet set”

Comment: isset() returns a boolean so you can also use `if(!isset($_COOKIE['somename']))` which means _is NOT set_. I think this may have been what you were trying to do in the first place.

Comment: Moronic me. Sorry for the dumb question & wasting your time. I think I need a break.

Comment: It's a simple oversight. I've spent _hours_ tracking down a missing semicolon. :)

Comment: he he.. Ya, sometimes! Oversight! Its a pain in the as* though.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies aren't set into `$_COOKIE` until the browser actually sends them.

It works something like this:

Request 1:

```
Your script starts
$_COOKIE is empty
session_start()
Your script ends
-> cookies to browser
```

Request 2:

```
<- browser sends cookies in request
Your script starts
$_COOKIE contains your cookie
...
```

Comment: I actually figured that out. But, Thanks. 
I still am not able to understand the isset part though.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey - The $_COOKIE is just a global variable of PHP and is filled before your script starts with information about real browser cookies. So if there are no cookies set in the browser before your script starts, $_COOKIE will be an empty array.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Moronic me. I have set the msg to be show when $_cookie['somename'] isset. Sorry for the dumb question & wasting your time.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey - Yes, i have seen Herbert's answer, that happens and we didn't see the problem neither, no problem.